# User Input of strings with if/else compare in NASM x86-64 Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have the question, how to make if/else statements with user Input (Strings) in NASM x86-64 for Linux ARM.
I don't get it how to do it.

I tried some online solutions with integers just modified to my thing but it didn't worked.
So as example as a C++ code:

```cpp
cout << "Enter name:";
cin >> name;

if (name == "max") {
 cout << "Access denied!" << endl;
}
```

Would be nice if anyone could help me but not only with solution. With explaining to understand it.
I am new at learning NASM so please be nice

This is what i have:

```
section .data
    txt1 db "Wie lautet dein Name? "
    txt2 db "Hallo, "

section .bss
    name: resb 128

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, txt1
    mov rdx, 22
    syscall

    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 128
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, txt2
    mov rdx, 7
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 128
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you know how to compare strings?

Comment: I... I don't know but i think no

Comment: This is the first step you need to find out how to do.  Do you know how you would do it in C++ if you couldn't just use `==` to compare the two?

Comment: No... I don't hink so...

Comment: okay.  To do that, you need to compare the strings character by character.  Two strings are equal if all characters in them are equal.  Have you worked with strings in assembly before?

Comment: Code blocks cannot be posted into comments.  Please don't do that.

Comment: I edited to show

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syscalls you're using (I assume this is Linux) but x86 has a few instructions to make strings easy. `repz cmpsb` can compare the strings one byte at a time. However you'll need to have one string's base pointer in `rsi`, the other in `rdi`, and the length of the shorter string in `rcx`. That should get you started. Also you will need the string `"max"` in your data section so you can compare with it.